# Using Docker to share projects to work on, on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I'm a junior web developer working in a small web agency. We work on windows 10, with wampserver and mainly with Prestashop, Wordpress and Symfony websites. For every task I am given a "ticket" for which I must develop on a new branch (if needed). When the work is done I merge my branch on the develop branch which is hosted on a preproduction server, and if it is considered ok, it is then merged on the master branch, which is the website in production hosted on another server.

I was given the task to do some research on Docker and to find how it could improve our workflow.

But from what I understood yet, docker containers are just similar to Virtual Machines and are only useful for building isolated environments in order to test an application without having to think about dependencies.

But given the fact that we already have a preproduction server, I don't see the point of using Docker ? Did I miss something ?

Also, could Docker be of use for sharing projects between teamworkers (we all work on Windows) ? (for example a developer is working on a website locally, can he create a container and its image that could be used instantly as it is without configurations by another developer to work on it on his part ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But from what I understood yet, docker containers are just similar to Virtual Machines and are only useful for building isolated environments in order to test an application without having to think about dependencies.

No, Docker containers are not only useful for testing.

When building a correct workflow with Docker you can achieve 100% parity between development, staging and production if all use the same docker images.

> But given the fact that we already have a preproduction server, I don't see the point of using Docker ? Did I miss something ?

This pre production server, aka what is normally called a `staging` server should also use docker to run the code.

> Also, could Docker be of use for sharing projects between teamworkers (we all work on Windows) ? (for example a developer is working on a website locally, can he create a container and its image that could be used instantly as it is without configurations by another developer to work on it on his part ?)

Yes... You create the base docker images with only the necessary stuff to run in production and from them you can build other docker images with the necessary developers tools.

Production image `company/app-name`:

```
FROM php:alpine

# other your production dependencies here
```

Assumming that ones build the docker image with name `company/app-name` then the image for development.

Development image `company/app-name-dev`:

```
FROM company/app-name

# add here only developer tools
```

Now the developer uses both images `company/app-name` and `company/app-name-dev` during development and in the staging server only `company/app-name` docker image will be used to run the code.

After soem months of interaction in this flow you may even fill confident to start using the `company/app-name` to deploy the app to production and now you are with a `100%` parity between development, staging and production.

Take a look to the [Php Docker Stack](https://gitlab.com/exadra37-docker/php/docker-stack) for some inspiration, because I built it with this goal in mind for my latest job, but I end up to leave the company when we where in the process of adopting it in development...

But don't put all services you need in one single docker image because that is a bad practice in docker, instead use one service per docker image, like one service for PHP, another for the database, another for the Nginx server, etc.. See [here](https://gitlab.com/exadra37-docker/php/docker-stack/blob/master/src/docker-compose.yml) how several services can be composed together with docker compose.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, this is a very complete answer. From the downvote I received I guess it was a stupid question but I clearly mentioned I was a junior developer so I don't get it. Anyway, thank you so much for your advices and your docker stack, it will definitely help me.

Comment: Glad to be able to help... let me know if the Php Docker Stack does not work on Windows, never test it there.

Comment: Ok, as soon as I test it I'll give you a feedback. Thanks again.